# Referencing services with Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm having issues calling what is supposed to have been defined in some Docker Compose services from my "main" (`web`) service. I have the following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '2'

services:
 db:
   image: postgres
   volumes:
    - postgres-db-volume:/data/postgres
 pdftk:
   image: mnuessler/pdftk
   volumes:
    - /tmp/manager:/work
 ffmpeg:
   image: jrottenberg/ffmpeg
   volumes:
    - /tmp/manager:/files
 web:
   build: .
   command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
   volumes:
     - .:/code
     - /tmp/manager:/files
   ports:
     - "8000:8000"
   depends_on:
     - db
     - pdftk
     - ffmpeg

volumes:
   postgres-db-volume:
```

I'm able to use `db` from `web` perfectly, but unfortunately not `pdftk` or `ffmpeg` (these are just command-line utilities that are undefined when I run `web`'s shell):

```
manager$ docker-compose run web bash
Starting manager_ffmpeg_1
Starting manager_pdftk_1
root@16e4b755172d:/code# pdftk
bash: pdftk: command not found
root@16e4b755172d:/code# ffmpeg
bash: ffmpeg: command not found
```

How can I get `pdftk` and `ffmpeg` to be defined within the `web` service? Is `depends_on` not the appropriate directive? Should I be extending `web`'s Dockerfile to call an entry-point script that installs the content found in the other two services (even though this'd seem counterproductive)?

Tried to remove and rebuild the `web` service after adding `pdftk` and `ffmpeg`, but that didn't solve it.

What can I do?

Thank you!

Comment: Try to run a single container as ```docker-compose run pdftk``` and than exec in this container and than try to run your command. Is it running ?

Comment: Or other possibilities are 1. command in not on $PATH 2. check +x permission on command file

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an misunderstanding of "depends_on". It is used to set a starting order for containers.

For example: Start Database before Webserver etc.

If you want access to tools, installed in other containers, you have to open an ssh connection for example:

```
ssh pdftk <your command>
```

But i would install the nessecary tools into the web container image.
Extend the Dockerfile to install both tools should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

> Edit: The described method below, does not work for the OP's question. Still leaving it here as *educational information*.

---

Besides the options described by @opHASnoNAME ... you could try declaring a container-volume for `pdftk` and `ffmpeg` and use the binaries directly, like so:

```
ffmpeg:
  volumes:
    - /usr/local/bin
```

and mount this on your web container:

```
web:
  volumes_from:
    - ffmpeg
```

**Please note that this approach has some limitations:**

- the path `/usr/local/bin` mounted from `ffmpeg` should not exist in web, otherwise you might need to mount the files, only.
- in `web`, `/usr/local/bin` must be in your `$PATH`.
- since this is kinda hotlinking of binaries, this might fail due to different Linux versions, missing shared libraries, etc... - so it actually works only for standalone binaries
- all containers using `volumes` and `volumes_from` have to be deployed on the same host

But I am still using this here and there, i.e. with the `docker` or `docker-compose` binaries.

Comment: It is by no means best practise to use a ssh tunnel for inter-container commucations. What you described above is very wrong and will fail horribly - not only because libs/configuration will be missing and broken as you have written yourself. This is even worse practise. If a binary is that kind of standalone, you can include it in the container (web) anyways. You do not separate by concerns anyway, using what you do

Comment: I removed the removed best-practice part for the other solution. And yes, mine is absolutely not best-practice, thought I'd have pointed that out.

Comment: removed my downvote due to you corrections - still i strongly advice to never do this kind of mount. It basically attacks anything docker wants you protect from. If you really need this, merge the containers into one image or even do not use docker at all

Comment: I agree with your statements - I also tried it with pdftk and ffmpeg - no chance. Edited my posting one more time. Thanks for your insights.

Answer (score 0):

To access the "tools" you do not need to install SSH, this is most probably pretty complicated and not wanted. The containers are not "merged into  one" when using depends_on.

Depends_on is even less then starting order, its more "ruff container start order. E.g. eventhough app depends on DB, it will happen, that the db container process did not yet get fully started while app has already been started - depends_on right now is, in most cases, rather used to notify when a container needs re-initialization when a other container he depends on e.g. does get recreated.

Other then that, start your containers and mount the docker-socket into them. Add this:

```
services:
web:   
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Now, on the webserver, where you need docker to be installed, you can do:

`docker exec pdftk <thecommand>`

Thats the usual way to run commands on services.

You can of course use http/api based implementations, in this case, you do not need to expose any ports or mount the socket, more, you can access the services using their service-name

`ping pdftk` or `ping ffmpeg`

Comment: What's about the fact that the web service container has full access to your docker host?

Comment: Give fact and can be more critical then running SSHD if you have more then this particial container-stack running on the host and you want the other containers to be isolated. In the end, secure isolation with docker is a very tough topic. I would consider this the most prominent flaw in the docker-socket mount, but its the best alternative among the really best one: Use a job-queue and run jobs or use a REST-API if you need blocking/sync requests

Comment: Thanks! Tried to add `/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` to the volumes, but I still can't use e.g. `pdftk` from `web`'s bash. I'm essentially trying to access the same as `docker-compose run pdftk` from `docker-compose run web bash`, but unsure as to how mounting the docker-socket can help. What should I do?

Comment: This could also be because the `pdftk` service exits immediately, and it's stopped by the time `web` tries to access it (as shown by `docker-compose ps`). If that's the case, though, then I'd either be looking for a command that starts the service when I call it or a way to keep `pdftk` running indefinitely... right?

Comment: docker-compose will not work in this context, since the docker-compose.yml file is missing - you have to pick the container_name if possible